# MATLAB fastinsert error

Tags: sql-server, matlab, matlab-table

I have a simple table in SqlServer database, `simSQLTable`. The column headings are:

```
index, del_date, name
```

I have a table in MATLAB `mytbl`, with one row:

```
num   deldate  myname
---   -------  ------
1     '07-02-2015 00:00:00.0'  'JenZ'

mycolnames = {'index', 'del_date', 'name'};
```

I use `fastinsert` like this:

```
fastinsert(conn, 'simSQLTable', mycolnames, mytbl);
```

but I get this error:

```
Error using database/fastinsert (line 90)
Variable fields and insert fields do not match.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that the column names in `mycolnames` pertain to the *database* table, not your MATLAB [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) `mytbl`. That has its own variable names given by `{'num' 'deldate' 'myname'}`, which don't match the database column names. From the [`fastinsert` documentation for the `data` argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/fastinsert.html#input_argument_d0e33598):

> Data to insert, specified as a numeric matrix, cell array, table, dataset array, or structure that contains all data for insertion into the existing database table `tablename`. If `data` is a structure, then field names in the structure must match `colnames`. If `data` is a table or a dataset array, then the variable names in the table or dataset array must match `colnames`.

To get around this, you can either [modify the variable names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table-properties.html#property_d0e986894) in your table so they match your database column names:

```matlab
mytbl.Properties.VariableNames = mycolnames;
fastinsert(conn, 'simSQLTable', mycolnames, mytbl);
```

Or you can just [extract the data from your table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) that needs to be inserted:

```matlab
fastinsert(conn, 'simSQLTable', mycolnames, mytbl.Variables);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fastinsert` queries the database to get the datatypes of the columns. This causes problems with reserved keywords. Try to use a back-tick `` ` `` in mySQL or `"` in Transact-SQL to quote the keyword `index`.

**mySQL:**

```
mycolnames = {'`index`', 'del_date', 'name'}
```

**Transact-SQL:**

```
mycolnames = {'"index"', 'del_date', 'name'}
```

Comment: Thanks. let me try. Also I just found out that I don't have write permission.